# How to insert a 1 automatically in an excel cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to put a value of 1 in an excel cell when it is selected. Cells that are not selected remain blank.

Comment: Have a look at change events, and put up what you've attempted so far

Comment: Thanks Tom, I am really new to vba / excel and have a spreadsheet that has stock items in column a and we enter a 1 in column b if we have stock but it takes ages if I have enter the 1 using the touch keypad so wanted to be able to just click the relevant cell in column b and it was populated with a 1.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveCell` will use the current cell that is selected then, as you can see, it assigns the value of 1 to that cell.

```
ActiveCell.value = 1
```

If you would like it to be more modular if it is perhaps occurring many times, then consider having a look at change events [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx), as suggested by @Tom

Answer (score 0):

I really don't recommend you doing this especially if this is for monitoring your stock and so for this time and this time only I've written it to make it a bit more safer if you're actually to do this BUT I DO NOT RECOMMEND IT.

you're going to need to paste this into the worksheet module that it relates to

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Columns.Count = 1 And Target.Rows.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 2 Then
        Target.Value = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

To get to the worksheet module you need to go into the vba editor (Shortcut Alt+F11 on windows) and paste in the correct worksheet module (Notice highlighted sheet)

[image]

I warn you though this could very quickly lead to your stock levels being inaccurate as this will run whenever you click on a cell or move around a worksheet with the arrow keys. This could mess up your whole system and there will be no undo (vba wipes the undo memory)

What would be much better to do is actually monitor your exact stock levels in excel, then use a formula such as (say you keep your stock level in column c)

```
=IF(C1>0, B1=1, B1=0)
```

This would then automatically accurately represent whether it was in stock or not.

Comment: Thanks Tom, how do I specify the columns if I wanted to add more columns that automatically get a  1 inserted. Also I know its a bit cheeky is there anyway I can change the 1 to a tick and how would I get a count of how many ticks are in a particular row. So say Column1 was the item then I had multiple columns of 1's or Ticks then a lst column to add the rows up. Can I apply it to a certain range of cells say 24 rows by 32 columns then have column  33 as the total for each row. Thanks Michael

Comment: You'd need to modify the `If` condition so it would be `...Or Target.Column = xx` You're opening up more trap doors for yourself doing it like that. You could use formatting in excel and wingdings to replace all the `1` in a range for ticks. Use custom formatting `[=1]"ü";"û"` and change the font to wingdings on the range

Comment: Thanks Tom have actually used it on another spreadsheet that we use for taking orders. Is there anyway I can specify the cells it applies to rather than the whole spreadsheet?

Comment: @MichaelGriffin the change event focuses on the whole worksheet. However if you change the condition of the 'if' you'll be able to look at a certain range. In my example it is set to firstly make sure that you have only selected one cell instead of a range. Then that it is in column 2 (B) by changing that you can get it to look at any party of the worksheet

Comment: Thanks as I said am really new to vba and am looking to learn, if i wanted it only to apply to a range of cells say B3 to D24 how would I do it? Its all a bit confusing at the moment just bought a vba book to have a read through so hopefully it will all start to become clearer ??

Comment: You'd want to look at replacing the `Target.Column = 2` with something along the lines of `Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B3:D24")) Is Nothing`

Comment: Hi Tom tried replacing Target.Column = 2 with the NotApplication.Intersect.... but it didnt like it am I doing something wrong?